# Write contents of a database field to a Batch File or.bat or .txt file in Django

Tags: django

Here is my code I am using the CSV writer as it is the only example I can find but it put unwanted delimiters in the file. I need just the code to export out  a text file which I can call .bat

```
@login_required     
def export_batchfiles(request, id, batchfileid): 

    code = get_object_or_404(Attachment_coder, pk=batchfileid)
    team = get_object_or_404(Team, pk=id)
    membership = Membership(request, team)

    # Create the HttpResponse object with the appropriate CSV header.
    response = HttpResponse(mimetype='text/plain')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="vpacode'+ '-' + code.firstName + '-' + code.lastName + '-' + code.clubName + '-' + code.grade + '-' + code.dateCreated +'.bat"'

    writer = csv.writer(response)

    writer.writerow([code.batchFile])

    return response
```

Answer (score 0):

Well just plainly put the file's content in the response's body:

```
response = HttpResponse(code.batchFile, mimetype='text/plain')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="vpacode'+ '-' + code.firstName + '-' + code.lastName + '-' + code.clubName + '-' + code.grade + '-' + code.dateCreated +'.bat"'

return response
```

Comment: Thanks aumo that was the answer I was looking for